# Comparing strings in cell arrays

Tags: string, matlab, compare, cell-array

I'm trying to find the most frequent word in a list of words. Here is my code so far:

```
uniWords = unique(lower(words));
for i = 1:length(words)
    for j = 1:length(uniWords)
        if (uniWords(j) == lower(words(i)))
            freq(j) = freq(j) + 1;
        end
    end
end
```

When I try to run the script, I get the following error:

```
Undefined function 'eq' for input arguments of
type 'cell'.

Error in Biweekly3 (line 106)
    if (uniWords(j) == lower(words(i)))
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You need to extract the *contents* of the cell with `{}`:

```
strcmpi(uniWords{j},words{i})
```

Also, I suggest comparing strings with `strcmp` or in this case [`strcmpi`, which ignores case](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi.html) so you do not need to call `lower`.

Be careful when using `==` on strings because they must be the same length or you will get an error:

```
>> s1='first';
>> s2='second';
>> s1==s2
Error using  == 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

Comment: +1 Wise advices. But you forgot an important one: vectorize! :-P

Comment: Yeah, yeah, yeah...  ;)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to do:

```
if (uniWords{j} == lower(words{i}))
```

Also, I suggest [not using `i` and `j` as variables in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

**Update**

As Chappjc points out, it is better to use `strcmp` (or in your case [`strcmpi`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi.html) and skip `lower`), since you want to ignore cases.

Comment: There is another issue with the code in the question. For strings of different length, using `==` will give `Matrix dimensions must agree.`

Answer (score 2):

No need for loops. `unique` gives you a unique identifier for each word, and you can then sum occurrences of each identifier with `sparse`. From that you easily find the maximum, and the maximizing word(s):

```
[~, ~, jj ] = unique(lower(words));
freq = full(sparse(ones(1,length(jj)),jj,1)); % number of occurrences of each word
m = max(freq);
result = lower(words(jj(freq==m))); % return more than one word if there's a tie
```

For example, with

```
words = {'The','hello','one','bye','the','one'}
```

the result is

```
>> result

result = 

    'one'    'the'
```